# How to get coordinates of cities from openstreetmap in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, openstreetmap

I have a vector of german city names, like

```
cities <- c("Munich", "Hamburg", "Gelsenkirchen", "Berlin", "Berlin", "Berlin", "Hamburg")
```

I would like to draw a map with red dots on any city in that list.
Specificly, I would like to

- create an openstreetmap section, which is just wide enough to include all cities in the list
- draw red points on the map for every city in the list, making the points bigger by the count of city names
- (optimally) not care about the actual coordinates of the cities, as openstreetmap "should know" them

So, how would I do this in R with ggplot?

This is how I got so far:

```
library(OpenStreetMap)

# List of cities
staedte <- tribble(
  ~Stadt, ~lon, ~lat,
  "HSNR", 6.56964 , 51.31655, 
  "Mönchengladbach", 6.4519, 51.2007
)

# get the map (this might take some time)
# and add some extra margin of 0.015
mymap <-openmap(c(min(staedte$lat)-0.015, min(staedte$lon)-0.015), 
            c(max(staedte$lat+0.015), max(staedte$lon)+0.015),
            type = "stamen-watercolor", mergeTiles = TRUE)

# project openstreetmap to alternate coordinate system (might also take some time)
mymap_coord <- openproj(mymap)

# create a ggplot2-Object of the map
mymap_plt <- OpenStreetMap::autoplot.OpenStreetMap(mymap_coord)

# add the city points
mymap_plt + 
  geom_point(data=staedte, aes(x=lon, y=lat, size=10), color="blue") +
  geom_text(data=staedte, aes(x=lon, y=lat+0.01, size=10, label=Stadt), color="blue")
```

This works quiet well. My problem is:

- right now I have to enter the lon and lat coordinates of the city by hand. Is there a way to get them just by the city name?
- how could I set the size of the points in relation to the count of the city?

Comment: You could try `getbb` from the `osmdata` package, which will return a bounding box for the city if you give it the name. eg, `osmdata::getbb("Berlin")`

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the comment of nwbort above regarding the coordinates part of your question:

The `osmdata`-package is the easiest way to go here since you can retrieve data based on the name of a city. However, it is a bit annoying to get the bounding box rather than the coordinates. Here is a suggestion for a function to obtain the bounding box and then calculate the centroid of the it (using the simple feature (`sf`) package).

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(osmdata)

city_coords_from_op_str_map <- function(city_name){
  city_coordinates <- osmdata::getbb(city_name) %>% # Obtain the bounding box corners fro open street map
    t() %>% # Transpond the returned matrix so that you get x and y coordinates in different columns
    data.frame() %>% # The next function takes a data frame as input
    sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y")) %>%  # Convert to simple feature
    sf::st_bbox() %>% # get the bounding box of the corners
    sf::st_as_sfc() %>% # convert bounding box to polygon
    sf::st_centroid() %>% # get the centroid of the polygon
    sf::st_as_sf() %>% # store as simple feature
    sf::`st_crs<-`(4326)  # set the coordinate system to WGS84 (GPS etc.)
  
  city_coordinates %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(name_of_city = city_name) %>% # add input city name in a column
    dplyr::rename(geometry = x) %>% # Rename the coordinate column
    dplyr::relocate(name_of_city, geometry) %>% # reorder the columns
    return()
}

alingsas <- city_coords_from_op_str_map("Alingsås") # Store coordinate of a city
travemunde <- city_coords_from_op_str_map("Travemünde") # Store coordinate of a city


cities_of_interest <- bind_rows(alingsas, travemunde) # join data of the different cities
```

As of the second part of your question, I have no suggestion for code, but if you put the population size of each city in another column, you can use that column to define the size of the symbol in your plot.